How come my radius is way small?

I cant seem to get the gap closed with the current radius span.
What can be done to get this with a usable range.
If I set to 0 the radially dispersement goes down to one unit.

Hello and welcome. Please don't crop out essential information from your screenshots, this hides away any details that could possibly hint at what your issue is. As it stands a partial screenshot of the subject without context or further information makes it impossible to diagnose the issue. Please edit your post and replace your images with full uncropped screenshots showing the user interface, properties, full node tree, and any relevant parameters that might help us solve the issue.

You've hit a floating point precision limitation. Typically in softwares such as blender you can really work in dimensions varying by a degree of up to 6-7 magnitudes. Here you have 7 significant digits so in a perfect world there is no gap but the renderer can't be precise enough to both render meters and render nanometers at the same time. Try changing the project units in the settings

Thank you for the answers. I made adjustments in previous nodes and the final object came out perfect.
